# App closing as soon as it loads, with no errors

Tags: c#, dbproviderfactories

One of my applications runs fine on my developing machine, although if I run it on another computer the app closes as soon as it loads.

I remember I got this problem one time when I didn't deploy the `app.config`, but I made sure it was deployed this time.

Since the application gives absolutely no errors and all the results from Google are misguided, I have no idea what to do.

What could be causing this behavior? Even though `app.config` is deployed I think it may be something about it or something about one or more references, but I'm not sure.

EDIT:

Apparently there was a call stack on the event logs

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(System.Type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at MyApp.Database.Repositories.GuidRepository.GetNewest()
   at MyApp.Components.Common.User.SystemGuid.SetupGuid()
   at MyApp.Form1.InitializeSoftWare()
   at MyApp.Form1..ctor()
   at MyApp.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown? Have you looked at event viewer to see if there's anything suspicious?

Comment: You deploy app.config?

Comment: Well, I could only suggest to check the startup code (Main and first form constructor and load method) to check if in these parts you have some external dependencies (a file or other resource) that should be present in the target machine

Comment: I edited the my post according to nimeshjm's tip.